# Google Analytics on intranet not tracking

Tags: google-analytics, intranet

I have an intranet that is accessed by local users on

```
http://intranet
```

and users around the country on

```
http://intranet.ourdomain.com
```

Users viewing the intranet from the external URL

```
http://intranet.ourdomain.com
```

have their activity tracked but those trying to access the intranet via

```
http://intranet
```

don't

I have tested it using a computer on the internal network and the machine can access:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js

http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif

https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js

https://ssl.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif
```

With no issues, and also if the machine navigates to http://intranet.ourdomain.com then that activity is tracked.

Anyone have any ideas why it is not tracking

```
http://intranet
```

connections.

NOTE: The tracking info is setup with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'ourdomain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-    analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Is it actually possible to track

```
http://intranet ???
```

Comment: Try to remove the `_setDomainName` line. If this doesn't work, try `'_setDomainName', 'none'`.

Comment: At least according to [this article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009688?hl=en), it's not possible to track intranet.

Comment: Ouch! I can't edit my comment, but there are articles mentioning the _setDomainName hack. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I did as @nwellnhof suggested and set

```
  '_setDomainName', 'none'
```

I also then add a filter to show the full URI in order to separate out the different environments. I got the filter info from here http://www.annielytics.com/how-to-add-a-hostname-filter-in-ga/